# Syntax sugar: _* for treating Seq as method parameters

Tags: scala, syntactic-sugar

I just noticed this construct somewhere on web:

```
val list = List(someCollection: _*)
```

What does `_*` mean? Is this a syntax sugar for some method call? What constraints should my custom class satisfy so that it can take advantage of this syntax sugar?

Answer (score 74):

Generally, the `:` notation is used for type ascription, forcing the compiler to see a value as some particular type.  This is not *quite* the same as casting.

```
val b = 1 : Byte
val f = 1 : Float
val d = 1 : Double
```

In this case, you're ascribing the special *varargs* type.  This mirrors the asterisk notation used for declaring a varargs parameter and can be used on a variable of any type that subclasses `Seq[T]`:

```
def f(args: String*) = ... //varargs parameter, use as an Array[String]
val list = List("a", "b", "c")
f(list : _*)
```

Comment: i tried returning an array of String like `String*` , i get an error that cannot resolve * . If i return `Array[String]` and pass it to a method with args  `(args: String*)` it says expecting String and not `Array[String]`

Answer (score 18):

That's scala syntax for exploding an array. Some functions take a variable number of arguments and to pass in an array you need to append `: _*` to the array argument.

Comment: Nitpick: the argument need only be a `Seq`, or implicitly convertible to a `Seq`.

Answer (score 1):

Variable (number of) Arguments are defined using *.
For example,

`def wordcount(words: String*) = println(words.size)`

wordcount expects a string as parameter,

```
scala> wordcount("I")
1
```

but accepts more Strings as its input parameter (_* is needed for Type Ascription)

```
scala> val wordList = List("I", "love", "Scala")
scala> wordcount(wordList: _*)
3
```