# Scala; Can you define many parameters as one

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Can you define a set of variables for later use?

Here are some pseudo code highlighting my intent:

```
def coordinates = x1, y1, x2, y2

log("Drawing from (%4.1f, %4.1f) to (%4.1f, %4.1f)".format(coordinates))
canvas.drawLine(coordinates, linePaint)
```

Here is a working example that contains duplicated code.

```
log("Drawing from (%4.1f, %4.1f) to (%4.1f, %4.1f)".format(x1, y1, x2, y2))
canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, linePaint)
```

Comment: Not sure what your intent is, maybe varags can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176440/syntax-sugar

Comment: Varags wont work. Varags must be the last parameter and thus isn't general.

Comment: Did you have a look at Scala macros? http://scalamacros.org/ They are an experimental feature, though.

Comment: Actually no as I'm on the 2.9.2 branch. But I will look into that on a later occasion.

Comment: Using macros for a problem like this seems a little excessive (and also probably a good way to make everyone who ever reads your code hate you).

Comment: How would macros help in this case? You’d then have to enhance the Android API with them.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can, although the syntax is arguably horribly clunky, and there are some limitations that may seem a little arbitrary at first. The trick is to convert the method to a function (called "eta expansion"), and then to use that function's `tupled` method to get something you can apply to a tuple.

Suppose you have a class like this:

```
class Foo {
  def f(a: String, b: String) = "%s, %s".format(b, a)
  def g(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) = x + y * z
}
```

And an instance:

```
val foo = new Foo
```

And some data you'd like to use `Foo`'s methods on:

```
val names = ("John", "Doe")
val nums = (42, 3, 37)
```

You can't just write `foo.f(names)` or `foo.g(nums)`, because the types don't line up—argument lists and tuples are different things in Scala. But you can write the following:

```
scala> (foo.f _).tupled(names)
res0: String = Doe, John

scala> (foo.g _).tupled(nums)
res1: Int = 153
```

Sticking the underscore after the method turns it into a function (this is in my opinion the most confusing little quirk of Scala's syntax), and `tupled` converts it from a function with two (or three) arguments to a function with a single tuple argument.

You could clean the code up a little by defining the following helper functions, for example:

```
scala> val myF = (foo.f _).tupled
myF: ((String, String)) => String = <function1>

scala> val myG = (foo.g _).tupled
myG: ((Int, Int, Int)) => Int = <function1>

scala> myF(names)
res2: String = Doe, John

scala> myG(nums)
res3: Int = 153
```

I'm not sure that's much better, though.

Lastly, you can't (conveniently) use this approach on a varargs method—you can't for example write the following:

```
val coordsTupleToString = ("(%4.1f, %4.1f) to (%4.1f, %4.1f)".format _).tupled
```

Or even just:

```
val coordsToString = "(%4.1f, %4.1f) to (%4.1f, %4.1f)".format _
```

Which is yet another reason to avoid varargs in Scala.

Comment: Thanks very resourceful post. Can this approach be used while having a method that use the first 4 parameters from a tuple and then later by normal use? Like m(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5) written as m(Tuple4, p5)

Comment: You can use this on varargs just fine as long as they are happy with the `Any` type: `printf("%d %d %d %s", (1,2,3,"fish").productIterator.toSeq: _*)`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need a tuple:

```
val coordinates = (x1, y1, x2, y2)
```

or maybe a full-blown object?

Comment: I don't think a `tuple` is what I'm after? Or can you auto expand them? Otherwise I have to do method(coordinates ._1, coordinates ._2, coordinates._3, coordinates._4) which isn't what I'm after

Comment: @Farmor: if you have control over method you want to call this way, you can easily extract tuple with: `val (x1, y1, x2, y2) = coordinates`

Comment: No I don't have that as it's Androids API which exposes `drawLine` on a `Canvas`. I was primarily interested in if Scala was able to define a set of parameters and then use them in a conceptual find and replace way.

Answer (score 0):

Now, this may be obvious, but if it annoys you in only a few cases, you can always enhance:

```
implicit def enhancedCanvas(canvas: Canvas) = new {
  // using bad and slow syntax. please change this in Scala 2.10.
  def drawLineC(coordinates: (Float, Float, Float, Float), paint: Paint) = {
    val (x1, y1, x2, y2) = coordinates
    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint)
  }
}
```

Another possibility, if you’re crazy enough. (Might be that an enhancement like this is already in Scalaz or Shapeless.)

```
implicit def enhTuple4[A,B,C,D](t: Tuple4[A,B,C,D]) = new {
  def |<[E] (f: (A, B, C, D) => E) = f(t._1, t._2, t._3, t._4)
}

// to be used as
val coordinates = (x1, y1, x2, y2)
coordinates |< (canvas.drawLine(_, _, _, _, linePaint))
```