# scala varargs (Any*) wrapped twice

Tags: scala, variadic-functions

```
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
      foo("hello")
  }

  def foo(args:Any*){
    bar(args)
  }

  def bar(args:Any *){
    println(args)
  }
```

Look the code above, the output is WrappedArray(WrappedArray(hello))

> The String 'hello' is wrapped twice, how to avoid this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the invocation of `bar`, write this:

```
bar(args: _*)
```

This tells the compiler to use the args in `args`, which at this point is very similar to a `Seq[T]`, and pass each of them separately to `bar`, instead of considering `args` as the first of the repeated parameters that `bar` accepts.

Comment: could you make some explanation?

Comment: @jilen This answer covered the topic fairly well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176440/syntax-sugar