# pass function arguments from a iterable in Scala?

Tags: function, scala, arguments

Is it possible to pass function arguments from a iterable in Scala?

```
val arguments= List(1,2)
def mysum(a:Int,b:Int)={a+b}
```

How would one call mysum using the List contents as arguments?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax sugar: \_\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176440/syntax-sugar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For it to work on lists you'll need to accomodate the `mysum` function to "varargs":

```
scala> def mysum ( args : Int* ) = args.sum
mysum: (args: Int*)Int

scala> val arguments = List(1,2)
arguments: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> mysum(arguments: _*)
res0: Int = 3
```