# How is type conversion achieved using : _*?

Tags: scala

`val t = Vector(1 to 3: _*)`
returns:

```
scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

`val t = Vector(1 to 3)`

returns :

```
scala.collection.immutable.Vector[scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive] = Vector(Range(1, 2, 3))
```

How is the type conversion from 
`scala.collection.immutable.Vector[scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive]`

to

```
 scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]
```

achieved using `: _*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the [companion object for `Vector`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Vector%24), namely the `apply[A](elems: A*): Vector[A]` method.

As you can see, the apply takes varargs as argument, so this:

```
val vec = Vector(1 to 3: _*)
```

expands the range (which is a sequence) to varargs, which ends up working effectively the same as typing:

```
val vec = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

While this:

```
val rangeVec = Vector(1 to 3)
```

does not expand the range. That means the *whole range* is treated as one of the argument in varargs. So it's possible to do:

```
scala> val rangeVec = Vector(1 to 3, 6 to 10)
rangeVec: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive] = Vector(Range(1, 2, 3), Range(6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
```

to have a vector of ranges.

Fun fact: If you want to flatten the ranges from the range vector, it's quite easy:

```
scala> rangeVec.flatten
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Comment: so _* is custom syntax for extending a range to varargs ?

Comment: @user470184 [I guess you can say so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176440/syntax-sugar-for-treating-seq-as-method-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

`1 to 3` creates a range object.

So `Vector(1 to 3)` creates a vector of range objects, not a vector of int.

`_*` extends the elements in the range into varargs, so it generates the vector you need.