# How to set column names to toDF() function in spark dataframe using a string array?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

For example,

```
val columns=Array("column1", "column2", "column3")
val df=sc.parallelize(Seq(
(1,"example1", Seq(0,2,5)),
(2,"example2", Seq(1,20,5)))).toDF(columns)
```

How can I set column name using string Array?
Is it possible to mention data types inside toDF()?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`toDF()` takes a *repeated parameter* of type `String`, so you can use the `_*` type annotation to pass a sequence:

```
val df=sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1,"example1", Seq(0,2,5)),
  (2,"example2", Seq(1,20,5)))).toDF(columns: _*)
```

For more on repeated parameters - see section 4.6.2 in the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).

Comment: Thanks..How to specify data type along with columns inside toDF()?

Comment: Thanksss.... this is exactly i'm searching for morre than an hour,,, thanks

Answer (score 8):

```
val df=sc.parallelize(Seq(
(1,"example1", Seq(0,2,5)),
(2,"example2", Seq(1,20,5)))).toDF("column1", "column2", "column3")
```

toDF() takes comma-seperated strings

Answer (score 6):

`toDF()` is defined in [Spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) as:

```
def toDF(colNames: String*): DataFrame
```

And so you need to turn your array to a *varargs* as also described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176440/syntax-sugar-for-treating-seq-as-method-parameters). That means you need to do the following:

```
val columns=Array("column1", "column2", "column3")
val df=sc.parallelize(Seq(
(1,"example1", Seq(0,2,5)),
(2,"example2", Seq(1,20,5)))).toDF(columns: _*)
```

(Add : _* to`columns` in `toDF`)