# Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values) returning List[Array[T]] instead of List[T]

Tags: scala

Let's say I have

```
public enum MyEnum {
  ..
}
```

When I invoke

```
java.util.Arrays.asList(MyEnum.values)
```

I get back

```
java.util.List[Array[MyEnum]]
```

instead of

```
java.util.List[MyEnum]
```

Why is that?

Am I missing some JavaConverter magic?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176440/syntax-sugar-for-treating-seq-as-method-parameters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature of the java method is

```
static <T> List<T>  asList(T... a)
```

, i.e. it takes variable number of arguments. You are passing a single array, so you are getting a list with a single array.

If you want to pass each element of the array as a separate argument, use the `_*`-annotation:

```
java.util.Arrays.asList(java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.values: _*)
```

If you want a Scala `List` instead, use `toList` directly on array:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.values.toList
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andrey Tyukin for pointing out the correct answer already.

I'm just copy-pasting the scala documentation for Ascription for completeness

> ## Ascription
>
> Type ascription is often confused with type annotation, as the syntax in Scala is identical. The following are examples of
> ascription:
>
> - Nil: List[String]
> - Set(values: _*)
> - "Daniel": AnyRef
>
> Ascription is basically just an up-cast performed at compile-time for
> the sake of the type checker. Its use is not common, but it does
> happen on occasion. **The most often seen case of ascription is
> invoking a varargs method with a single Seq parameter**. This is done
> by ascribing the _* type (as in the second example above).
>
> Ascription follows the type annotation conventions; a space follows
> the colon

Comment: Hm, interesting. I'm not sure why it's called a "type ascription" in the documentation. Stuff like `List(1, 2, 3): _*` does not seem to be a valid expression on its own, whereas `"foo": AnyRef` certainly is. The error message in the compiler calls the `_*`-gizmo an "annotation". The `_*` seems more like a special case for supporting java-style varargs.

Comment: It's kinda like doing `: Seq[??]`, so I guess that's why it's called that @AndreyTyukin. It's also the same syntax.